# What is down -34% in stock terms?

Tags: stocks, investing, starting-out-investing, losses

Apple is now at 100.54, all time high is 134.54, #AAPL is now down -34%.

I fail to comprehend the above sentence. The way I usually interpret it,
say if a stock all time high is 100, it is down 30%, then the stock should now be 70.

But that minus sign; -34% seems to make a difference. It will be divided by 1.34 instead.

Is this the usual way of reporting downwards percentage? This is the first time I have seen it.

And what's the logic behind such representation?

Comment: Where did you read this?  I agree, I would describe that as down ~25%.  But reporters aren't typically very mathematically literate.

Comment: That's a pretty sloppy sentence, and it's mathematically wrong. It went down 34 points, starting at 134.54, so it's down by 34/134.54, which is 25%.

Comment: "Down -34%" sounds like "up 34%" to me!

Comment: The logic behind the representation seems to be that the person that wrote it didn't know what they are doing.

Comment: I read that here, https://twitter.com/OwensAssetFund/status/684752018846556160

Comment: OwensAssetFund sounds like a 'pump and dump' outfit to me. I wouldn't trust them for investment advice.

Comment: @PeterK. if only my balance thought the same as you

Comment: @Aequitas ;-) if wishes were fishes... :-)

Comment: 180.28 is down `-34%` (-45.74) from 134.54

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is mathematically wrong and verbally unclear.
Mathematically, you calculate the downwards percentage by

```
(old price - new price) / old price
```

So, it should be

```
(134.54 - 100.54) / 134.54 = 25,27%.
```

Verbally, the reporter should have written "The stock is down by 25%", not "down by -25%".

Comment: I shorthand this calculation with: (new price / old price) - 1